# How extract only groups without the whole match as output from String.match()?

Tags: javascript

I have regular expression `const entryRegexp = /^([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,3})-([\d]{1,2})/;`

```
const pressmark = "1-1-1-1";
const entryRegexp = /^([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,3})-([\d]{1,2})/;
const pressmarkPiecesMatch = pressmark.match(entryRegexp).slice(1);`
// output ["1", "1", "1", "1"] is fine
```

Can I do it without `String.slice`? I want use `String.match` and get only groups without whole match `"1-1-1-1"`. Usage `String.slice` may throws exception when `String.match` returns null.

Comment: I seem found a solution. I think that I can use `RegExp.test` before execute `String.slice` at array got from `String.match`. But the question stays the question how extract only groups as output from `String.match` if it is possible? :)

Comment: What do you want as a result?

Comment: @P.Ellul I want an array like this `["1", "1", "1", "1"]` instead `["1-1-1-1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]` where `"1-1-1-1"` is the whole match. I need only groups.

Comment: What is wrong with a good old fashioned `if` statement: `if (pressmarkPiecesMatch) pressmarkPiecesMatch = pressmarkPiecesMatch.slice(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like the answer I am providing, but what about creating a helper or adding a prototype to the String object?

**Helper**

```js
const strictMatch = function (regexp, value) {
  return regexp.test(value) ? value.match(regexp).slice(1) : null;
}

//Usage
const pressmark = "1-1-1-1";
const entryRegexp = /^([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,3})-([\d]{1,2})/;
const pressmarkPiecesMatch = strictMatch(entryRegexp, pressmark);
```

**Prototype**

```js
String.prototype.strictMatch = function (regexp) {
  return regexp.test(this) ? this.match(regexp).slice(1) : null;
}

//Usage
const pressmark = "1-1-1-1";
const entryRegexp = /^([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,3})-([\d]{1,2})/;
const pressmarkPiecesMatch = pressmark.strictMatch(entryRegexp);
```

Comment: I'm glad it helps!